# How can I add a UIElement to a Windows Forms application?

Tags: wpf, winforms, uielement

I have a WPF custom control I'd like to add to a Windows Forms application.
So I added a reference to the WPF assembly, created an ElementHost and set the Child property in code.

Is there a way to do this with drag and drop i e without writing code?
I have tried the ElementHost popup but it does not list my component.
As far as I can see, it lists only WPF components that are in a *project* (as opposed to an external *assembly*).

Answer (score 3):

When you will drop element host to window form it will show drop down to select the child then you can add WPF custom controls without code.

Comment: That's exacly my problem: the drop down does not list my component.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!